# Как поменять меню через хук?

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим имеется два меню: `menu 1`  и `menu 2`, созданные в админке `Внешний вид - Меню`
Как можно через дочернюю тему на разных страницах вывести эти меню?
т.е. чтобы на одной странице было `menu 1`, а на другой `menu 2`
нужно это сделать именно через дочернюю тему.
Можно ли это как-то сделать через хук `pre_wp_nav_menu`?
по умолчанию выбрано меню `menu 1`, и нужно допустим в условии проверить ID страницы, и вывести меню `menu 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо использовать другой фильтр - `wp_get_nav_menu_object`. Рабочий код:

```
/**
 * Filters the nav_menu term retrieved for wp_get_nav_menu_object().
 *
 * @param WP_Term|false      $menu_obj Term from nav_menu taxonomy, or false if nothing had been found.
 * @param int|string|WP_Term $menu     The menu ID, slug, name, or object passed to wp_get_nav_menu_object().
 *
 * @return false|WP_Term
 */
function wp_get_nav_menu_object_filter( $menu_obj, $menu ) {
    if ( $menu_obj && is_page( 'so892534' ) ) {
        remove_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_object', 'wp_get_nav_menu_object_filter', 10, 2 );
        $menu_obj = wp_get_nav_menu_object( 'menu-so892534' );
        return $menu_obj;
    }

    return $menu_obj;
}

add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_object', 'wp_get_nav_menu_object_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Замените в этом примере слаг страницы `so892534` и её меню `menu-so892534`.

Результат можно посмотреть на странице тестового сайта http://test.kagg.eu/so892534/.